# How do I force "pull-left" when used inside of "text-right"?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `img` tag, as you see in the code, with the class `.pull-left`  which is inside of the class `.text-right` which doesn't seem to let `pull-left` work correctly. It's like the class `.text-right` has priority over `.pull-left`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body text-right">
      <img class="pull-left" style="position:absolute;" src="http://placehold.it/125x125/000/fff">
      <strong class="pull-right">item</strong>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div>text</div>
      <div>text</div>
      <div>text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can try to apply the class to its container with its width set. There should be no problem

Answer (score 0):

Created a basic wrapper parent div with text right below the image. The reason this was happening us because that's exactly how CSS is supposed to work.

A child element inside a parent will take on the characteristics of that parent container

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <img class="pull-left" src="http://placehold.it/125x125/000/fff">
      <div class="text-right">
      <strong>item</strong>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div>text</div>
      <div>text</div>
      <div>text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <strong class="pull-left"> text</strong>
      <span class="pull-right">text</span>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: The confusing part to beginners in bootstrap is that using those alignment classes inside your html can sometimes put you in a bind, just like it did here. Sometimes it's better to assign alignment within your css. Works well if your using LESS or SASS nesting.

Comment: However, I use bootstrap often, and use text center in my html likes it's going out of style.